# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

Tags: javascript

пытаюсь скрыть футер с задержкой, но вылазит ошибка в консоли, не понимаю почему...

```html
<footer id="footer"></footer>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  window.onload = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.querySelector('#footer').style.display = 'none';
    }, 5000);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Ну наверное потому что в момент поиска `#footer` - его ещё не существует. Вам нужно другое событие [Document: DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Comment: @EzioMercer вообще onload тоже должен работать. Причём намного больше шансов с ним)) Мне кажется автор чего-то не упомянул....т.к. решение вполне рабочее

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да, точно, я забыл что он помимо того что я упомянул ещё и дожидается загрузки ресурсов)

Comment: @EzioMercer да вообще времени хватает, чтобы всё прогрузилось, но происходит ошибка в консоли

Comment: а как этот код в jquery будет выглядеть?

Comment: Такс, стоп, неважно как это будет выглядеть :) Вы лучше ответьте) Вы `footer` динамечски добавляете?

Comment: @EzioMercer да))

Comment: Прекрасно, потому вы его и не находите :) Т.к. добавляете динамически, то будет (по мне) прекрасно, если вы просто запомните его в какую-то переменную и будете к нему так обращаться

Comment: @EzioMercer я раньше тоже динамические скрывал таким кодом, но сейчас чего-то не получается, не пойму, даже увеличивая время ожидания

Comment: Дело не в том сколько вы ждёте. А в том, когда обращаетесь. В момент, когда заканчивается `window.onload` и запускается ваша ф-ия `footer`-а ещё нет на странице. Когда вы пишите ф-ию в `setTimeout` - это не значит что она создастся только через указанное время, оно создастся сразу, но выполнится потом. А в момент создания он уже пытается найти то что на странице не существует вот и ругается вам. Потому вам надо либо после создания к нему обратиться, либо ссылку на него навесить, чтобы можно было обратиться, когда надо

Comment: Я ж говорю тут явная недоговорочка. Так что, автор, добавляй полный код.......а целом проблема не раз тут обсуждалась и можно было и поиском воспользоваться.

Comment: @EzioMercer ага, понял, а как навешивается ссылка?

Comment: Всмысле? Просто сохраните куда-нибудь ваш `footer`, после создания. Типа `const footer = document.createElement('footer');`

Comment: @EzioMercer
а, вы про это)) 
подскажите, я так понял проблема в том, что футер находится внутри другого #document 
я так понимаю нужно как-то это добавить в код, типа
document.document.querySelector('#footer') )))
как это правильно сделать?

Comment: Как вы сделали вывод на счёт ещё одного `#document`?? Где я такое сказал? Фитер находится там где ему указано. Вы же его сами создаёте в чём проблема записать куда-то? Зачем вам эти селекторы? Ну если уж так сильно хотите через селекторы, то не вызывайте `querySelector` внутри `window.onload`, т.к. его там пока что нет. После вставки в документ, вызываёте свой `setTimeout` или сразу ему задайте стили